# What is the physical significance of reduced zone scheme?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

Different energy bands can be drawn in different zones in $k$-space is called **Extended-Zone-Scheme**, whereas if the different bands are drawn in first Brillouin zone, then its called **Reduced Zone Scheme**. If every band is drawn in every zone in $k$-space is known as **Periodic Zone Scheme**.

Is there any physical significance of reduced or periodic zone schemes? or is it just a geometrical convenience.

Comment: Can you give some more background to the question?

Comment: @BrendanDarrer No, The question says it all.

Comment: fine, no problem!

Answer (score 3):

The lattice momenta that differ by a reciprocal lattice vector are equivalent - this is the basis for drawing *reduced zone scheme* in  place of the *extended zone scheme*. The two are mathematically equivalent, but one typically discusses processes in a solid state in terms of the reduced scheme, where several energy states (bands) correspond to the same momentum - understanding that these momenta are limited to the first Brillouin zone.

Periodic zone scheme is redundant, as it shows the same states multiple times.

Comment: Does that mean it is a geometrical convenience?

Comment: @147875 One could say so... but it seems like complicating things beyond necessary. Why do you think that the extended scheme is more natural?

Comment: Extended zone scheme seems more natural because it is the effect of all the Bragg planes at each $\pm k$ on free electron parabola. Whereas in reduced zone scheme, you are re-drawing all bands in a first Brillouin zone.

Comment: The reduced zone scheme makes it easier to understand and follow interband transitions. In particular optical excitations, which have a selection rule of $\Delta k = 0$